# Slide Navigation menu with limited space

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

Hello I would like to seek advice on how to code to achieve this design (image 1) and navigate.

I have 5 navigation items but I have limited space and my goal is to show only 3 items at a time which is why I put arrow on left and right so when you click the respective arrow it will show the other menu while hide the other 2.

I'm using bootstrap and font awesome for arrows

[Goal Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0pyg.png)

[image]

[Current](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWozB.png)

[image]

Comment: Can you add HTML.

Comment: Horizontal scroll menu with arrow. Ref: [Link1-W3S](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_menu_horizontal_scroll.asp) [Link2-JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yfqyq9a9/2/) [Link3-Codepen](https://codepen.io/mahish/pen/RajmQw)

Comment: @TamilvananN i think last two links(jsfiddle and codepen) are very useful for the solution.

Comment: @TamilvananN Thank you i have used link2 and working

Answer (score 0):

you can use owl Carousel and show 3 elements rest will be hidden and scroll when click. check the demo.
https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/basic.html